# Unexpected output with fork()

Tags: c, unix, process, output, fork

I read somewhere that in Unix, after fork() is executed successfully, both processes will start their execution **at the next statement following** the fork() call. 
Meanwhile when I run this code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf(" do ");
   if(fork()!=0) printf ("ma ");
   if(fork()==0) printf ("to \n");
   else printf("\n")

    return 0;
}
```

one possible output is

```
 do ma
 do ma to
 do 
 do to
```

"printf(" do ");" is **before** the fork() call so how comes "do" is repeated several times in the output?

Comment: you're forking TWICE... it should be `pid = fork(); if (pid) { ... } else { ...}` to detect if you're in the child or parent. and since your `do` output has no line break, it sits in the output buffer until a line break is encountered, which is **AFTER** your fork. so you have two buffers with `do` sitting in them.

Comment: Someone else find the dups - there are loads - stdout buffering thing.

Comment: Than you for your answer. I know I'm forking twice, it is done on purpose, it is an exercice from my teacher where I should predict the output, but I still don't understand why do is written several times as it is before any of the two fork() calls.

Comment: OK, I found one of the dups:)

Comment: I think the "do"s are there because they are buffered in the parent output memory which is copied to all children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the definition of fork it says that the child and parent are exact same copy and both start executing at the next instruction.
Now, Since C doesn't flush output until a newline is printed or you explicitly flush output, the "do" stays in buffer and gets copied to child too.
use:

```
printf(" do ");
fflush(stdout);
```

or

```
printf(" do \n"); //Notice the newline in the end
```

and you will get expected output

Comment: This is nothing to do with "middle-level" vs. "high-level".

Comment: middle level vs high level is pretty abstract to such interpretations. Still removed it as it wasn't part of the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(fork()!=0) printf ("ma ");
```

This line creates two processes; one of them is the parent and runs the printf statement, and one is the child and doesn't.

```
   if(fork()==0) printf ("to \n");
```

Both processes run this statement; the result is four processes:

1. Parent-parent; this runs the first printf and prints " do ma "
2. Parent-child; this runs both and prints " do ma to \n"
3. Child-parent; this runs neither and prints " do "
4. Child-child; this runs the second and prints " do to \n"

The issue you have is that you think the fork return "skips" to the next statement; rather, when fork returns, you now have two processes with different return values. Typically, printf is not flushed until the program ends or you print a newline.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "do"s are there because they are buffered in the parent output memory which is copied to all children.

If you add "\n" to the first "do":

```
printf(" do\n");
```

you will not see any "do" after the fork.